# Bamboo Agent not showing up

Tags: ubuntu, continuous-integration, bamboo

One of the Bamboo agents doesn't show up in the list of agent on the Bamboo server, I looked at the the Troubleshooting guide, double checked the agentServer URL, wrapper config is the same as with the working agents.

No errors reported in the log, and according to the log it is " checking build queue for executables..." and receiving other Bamboo messages, but for some reason remains invisible to the Bamboo web interface.

What else can I check that may be causing it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was Java version that was too new, the solution was to install version 1.8.0

`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Comment: Yes it turns out that openjdk 11 doesn't work (despite it saying 11 is supported) I had to change to version 8 and then everything started working.